# How was the author's depiction of the sealed scroll in Revelation 5 influenced by the Old Testament?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 5:1 (YLT)

> And I saw upon the right hand of Him who is sitting upon the throne a scroll, **written within and on the back**, sealed with seven seals;
>
> ...

For instance, the fact that the sealed scroll was written on the front and back looks like it came straight from Ezekiel 2:9-10:

> ...
>
> And I look, and lo, a hand is sent forth unto me, and lo, **in it a roll of a book**,
>
> and He spreadeth it before me, **and it is written in front and behind**, and written on it are lamentations, and mourning, and wo!
>
> ...

What else in the Old Testament influenced John's depiction of this scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sealed scroll mentioned in Isaiah 29:1-14 (YLT):

> Wo to Ariel, Ariel, The city of the encampment of David! Add year to year, let festivals go round.
>
> **And I have sent distress to Ariel**, And it hath been lamentation and mourning, And it hath been to me as Ariel.
>
> **And I encamped, O babbler, against thee, And I laid siege against thee -- a camp. And I raised up against thee bulwarks.**
>
> And thou hast been low, From the earth thou speakest, And from the dust makest thy saying low, And thy voice hath been from the earth, As one having a familiar spirit, And from the dust thy saying whisperest,
>
> And as small dust hath been The multitude of those scattering thee, And as chaff passing on the multitude of the terrible, And it hath been at an instant -- suddenly.
>
> By Jehovah of Hosts thou art inspected, With thunder, and with an earthquake, And great noise, hurricane, and whirlwind, And flame of devouring fire.
>
> And as a dream, a vision of night, hath been **The multitude of all the nations Who are warring against Ariel, And all its warriors, and its bulwark, Even of those distressing her.**
>
> And it hath been, as when the hungry dreameth, And lo, he is eating, And he hath waked, and empty is his soul, And as when the thirsty dreameth, And lo, he is drinking, and he hath waked, And lo, he is weary, and his soul is longing, So is the multitude of all the nations Who are warring against mount Zion.
>
> **Tarry and wonder, look ye, yea, look, Be drunk, and not with wine, Stagger, and not with strong drink.**
>
> **For poured out on you hath Jehovah a spirit of deep sleep, And He closeth your eyes -- the prophets, And your heads -- the seers -- He covered.**
>
> **And the vision of the whole is to you, As words of the sealed book, That they give unto one knowing books, Saying, 'Read this, we pray thee,' And he hath said, 'I am not able, for it is sealed;'**
>
> And the book is given to him who hath not known books, Saying, 'Read this, we pray thee,' And he hath said, 'I have not known books.'
>
> And the Lord saith: Because drawn near hath this people, with its mouth, And with its lips they have honoured Me, And its heart it hath put far off from Me, And their fear of Me is -- A precept of men is taught!
>
> **Therefore, lo, I am adding to do wonderfully with this people, A wonder, and a marvel, And perished hath the wisdom of its wise ones, And the understanding of its intelligent ones hideth itself.'**
>
> ...

That the meaning of what God was telling through the prophets would be hidden (sealed) is a theme in Isaiah.

Isaiah 28:7-13

> ...
>
> **And even these through wine have erred, And through strong drink have wandered, Priest and prophet erred through strong drink, They have been swallowed up of the wine, They wandered because of the strong drink, They have erred in seeing, They have stumbled judicially.**
>
> For all tables have been full of vomit, Filth -- without place!
>
> By whom doth He teach knowledge? And by whom doth He cause to understand the report? The weaned from milk, the removed from breasts,
>
> For rule is on rule, rule on rule, line on line, line on line, A little here, a little there,
>
> **For by scorned lip, and by another tongue, Doth He speak unto this people.**
>
> Unto whom He hath said, 'This is the rest, give ye rest to the weary, And this -- the refreshing:' And they have not been willing to hear,
>
> And to whom a word of Jehovah hath been, Rule on rule, rule on rule, line on line, line on line, A little here, a little there, **So that they go and have stumbled backward, And been broken, and snared, and captured**.
>
> ...

Also Isaiah 6:9-10:

> ...
>
> And He saith, ‘Go, and thou hast said **to this people, Hear ye – to hear, and ye do not understand, And see ye – to see, and ye do not know.**
>
> **Declare fat the heart of this people, And its ears declare heavy, And its eyes declare dazzled, Lest it see with its eyes, And with its ears hear, and its heart consider, And it hath turned back, and hath health.’**
>
> ...

Expanding on the Ezekiel example in the original question, we read this in Ezekiel 2:1-10 and 3:1-11

> It is the appearance of the likeness of the honour of Jehovah, and I see, and fall on my face, and I hear a voice speaking, and He saith unto me, ‘Son of man, stand on thy feet, and I speak with thee.’
>
> And the doth come into me a spirit, when He hath spoken unto me, and it causeth me to stand on my feet, and I hear Him who is speaking unto me.
>
> And He saith unto Me, ‘**Son of man, I am sending thee unto the sons of Israel, unto nations who are rebels, who have rebelled against Me; they and their fathers have transgressed against Me, unto this self-same day.**
>
> **And the sons are brazen-faced and hard-hearted to whom I am sending thee**, and thou hast said unto them: Thus said the Lord Jehovah:
>
> and they – **whether they hear, or whether they forbear, for a rebellious house they are** – have known that a prophet hath been in their midst.
>
> ‘And thou, son of man, thou art not afraid of them, yea, of their words thou art not afraid, for briers and thorns are with thee, and near scorpions thou art dwelling, of their words thou art not afraid, and of their faces thou art not frightened, **for they are a rebellious house,**
>
> And thou hast spoken My words unto them, whether they hear or whether they forbear, **for they are rebellious.**
>
> ‘And thou, son of man, hear that which I am speaking unto thee: **Thou art not rebellious like the rebellious house,** open thy mouth, and eat that which I am giving unto thee.’
>
> And I look, and lo, a hand is sent forth unto me, and lo, in it a **roll of a book,**
>
> and He spreadeth it before me, **and it is written in front and behind**, and written on it are lamentations, and mourning, and wo!
>
> And He saith unto me, ‘Son of man, that which thou findest eat, eat this roll, and go, speak unto the house of Israel.’
>
> And I open my mouth, and He causeth me to eat this roll.
>
> And He saith unto me, ‘Son of man, thy belly thou dost feed, and thy bowels thou dost fill with this roll that I am giving unto thee;’ and I eat it, and it is in my mouth as honey for sweetness.
>
> And He saith unto me, ‘Son of man, go, enter in unto the house of Israel, and thou hast spoken with My words unto them.
>
> For, not unto a people deep of lip and heavy of tongue art thou sent – unto the house of Israel;
>
> not unto many peoples, deep of lip and heavy of tongue, whose words thou dost not understand. If I had not sent theem unto them – they, they do hearken unto thee,
>
> **but the house of Israel are not willing to hearken unto thee, for they are not willing to hearken unto Me, for all the house of Israel are brazen-faced and strong-hearted.**
>
> ‘Lo, I have made thy face strong against their face, and thy forehead strong against their forehead.
>
> As an adamant harder than a rock I have made thy forehead; thou dost not fear them, nor art thou affrighted before them, **for a rebellious house are they.**
>
> And He saith unto me, ‘Son of man, all My words, that I speak unto thee, receive with thy heart, and with thine ears hear; and go, enter in unto the Removed, unto the sons of thy people, and thou hast spoken unto them, and hast said unto them: Thus said the Lord Jehovah: whether they hear, or whether they forbear.’
>
> ...

And then in Ezekiel 12:1-2 it says the same thing we read in Isaiah 6:

> And there is a word of Jehovah unto me, saying,
>
> 'Son of man, **in the midst of the rebellious house thou art dwelling, that have eyes to see, and they have not seen; ears they have to hear, and they have not heard; for a rebellious house are they.**
>
> ...

So when John wrote the book of Revelation it was understood that much of what God told through the prophets was sealed. Here are 5 examples showing that prophecy was sealed.

Daniel 8:26-27

> ...
>
> And the appearance of the evening and of the morning, that is told, is true; and thou, hide thou the vision, for it is after many days.'
>
> And I, Daniel, have been, yea, I became sick for days, and I rise, and do the king's work, and am astonished at the appearance, **and there is none understanding.**

Daniel 12:5-9

> ...
>
> And I have looked – I, Daniel – and lo, two others are standing, one here at the edge of the flood, and one there at the edge of the flood, and he saith to the one clothed in linen, who is upon the waters of the flood, ‘Till when is the end of these wonders?’
>
> And I hear one clothed with linen, who is upon the waters of the flood, and he doth lift up his right hand and his left unto the heavens, and sweareth by Him who is living to the age, that, ‘After a time, times, and a half, and at the completion of the scattering of the power of the holy people, finished are all these.’
>
> **And I have heard, and I do not understand**, and I say, ‘O my lord, what is the latter end of these?’
>
> And he saith, **‘Go, Daniel; for hidden and sealed are the things till the time of the end;**

This is a New Testament example but it references the Old Testament.

Luke 18:31-34:

> ...
>
> And having taken the twelve aside, he said unto them, ‘Lo, we go up to Jerusalem, and all things shall be completed – **that have been written through the prophets** – to the Son of Man,
>
> for he shall be delivered up to the nations, and shall be mocked, and insulted, and spit upon,
>
> and having scourged they shall put him to death, and on the third day he shall rise again.”
>
> **And they none of these things understood, and this saying was hid from them, and they were not knowing the things said.**
>
> ...

Here is another New Testament example, but it quotes the Old Testament in Isaiah 6 which we quoted above.

John 12:12-17, 37-41

> ...
>
> On the morrow, a great multitude that came to the feast, having heard that Jesus doth come to Jerusalem,
>
> took the branches of the palms, and went forth to meet him, and were crying, ‘Hosanna, blessed is he who is coming in the name of the Lord - the king of Israel;’
>
> and Jesus having found a young ass did sit upon it, according as it was written,
>
> ‘Fear not, daughter of Sion, lo, thy king doth come, sitting on an ass’ colt.’
>
> **And these things his disciples did not know at the first**, but when Jesus was glorified, then they remembered that these things were having been written about him, and these things they did to him.
>
> The multitude, therefore, who are with him, were testifying that he called Lazarus out of the tomb, and did raise him out of the dead; because of this also did the multitude meet him, because they heard of his having done this sign,
>
> ...
>
> yet he having done so many signs before them, they were not believing in him,
>
> that the word of Isaiah the prophet might be fulfilled, which he said, ‘Lord, who gave credence to our report? and the arm of the Lord – to whom was it revealed?’
>
> Because of this **they were not able to believe, that again Isaiah said,**
>
> **‘He hath blinded their eyes, and hardened their heart, that they might not see with their eyes, and understand with the heart, and turn back, and I might heal them;’**
>
> these things said Isaiah, when he saw his glory, and spake of him.
>
> ...

Here is yet another New Testament example, but it reference the Old Testament too.

Acts 13:26-29

> ...
>
> ‘Men, brethren, sons of the race of Abraham, and those among you fearing God, to you was the word of this salvation sent,
>
> **for those dwelling in Jerusalem, and their chiefs, this one not having known, also the voices of the prophets, which every sabbath are being read – having judged him – did fulfill,**
>
> CSB - **“Since the residents of Jerusalem and their rulers did not recognize him or the sayings of the prophets that are read every Sabbath, they have fulfilled their words by condemning him.**
>
> and no cause of death having found, they did ask of Pilate that he should be slain,
>
> and when they did complete all the things written about him, having taken him down from the tree, they laid him in a tomb;
>
> ...